# Why file not found when I invoke runWithEntrypoint:libraryURI: on a FlutterEngine?

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios

I try to specify an entrypoint function in a specific file to launch a Flutter screen from my iOS APP, I follow the [doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/ios/add-flutter-screen?tab=entrypoint-library-swift-tab#dart-library) but get an error:

`Dart Error: Dart_LookupLibrary: library 'hh.dart' not found.`

This is my code in Xcode:

`flutterEngine.run(withEntrypoint: "hhPage", libraryURI: "hh.dart")`

and partial directory structure in the flutter module:

```
lib/
├─ main.dart
└─ hh.dart
```

Comment: I have the same

Answer (score 2):

The [doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/ios/add-flutter-screen?tab=entrypoint-library-swift-tab#dart-library) is not correct or out of date. According to [the doc comment of `libraryURI` argument](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/279e3af0a1c8f19286dded8aabbfbf752c2a55fe/shell/platform/darwin/ios/framework/Headers/FlutterEngine.h#L222-L224), we need to specify a string including its package name, like "package:your_package/hh.dart".

```dart
flutterEngine.run(withEntrypoint: "hhPage", libraryURI: "package:your_package_name/hh.dart")
```

Additionally, hh.dart has to be imported in main.dart to contain the file in the app.